# ¿Como colocar 2 lineas en una sola highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Necesito colocar estos resultados en una sola barra que la roja este junto a la verde adjunto la imagen estoy utilizando la librería de **highcharts**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
chartCPU = new Highcharts.chart('graf', 
                {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Paises visitados'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        gridLineWidth: 1,
                        categories: 
                        [
                            <?php
                                foreach($param['PAIS'] as $PAIS)
                                {
                                    echo "'$PAIS',";
                                }
                            ?>
                        ]
                    },
                    yAxis: 
                    [
                        {
                            min: 0,
                            title: 
                            {
                                text: '',
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.1,
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        split: true
                    },
                    series: 
                    [
                        {
                            name: 'EXITOSO',
                            data: 
                            [
                                <?php 
                                    for ($j=0; $j < count($param['TOTAL_EXITOSO']) ; $j++) 
                                    { 
                                        echo $param['TOTAL_EXITOSO'][$j].','; 
                                    }
                                ?>
                            ],
                            color: '#006400',
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'NO EXITOSO',
                            data: 
                            [
                                <?php 
                                    for ($l=0; $l < count($param['TOTAL_NOEXITOSO']) ; $l++) 
                                    { 
                                        echo $param['TOTAL_NOEXITOSO'][$l].','; 
                                    }
                                ?>
                            ],
                            color: '#B22222',
                            cursor: 'pointer'
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como primera medida deberas indicar que series quieres apilar. Esto se logra con el atributo `stack`, de la siguiente manera:

```
series: {
    stack: id
}
```

En tu caso te quedaria algo asi:

```
                series: 
                [
                    {
                        name: 'EXITOSO',
                        data: 
                        [
                            <?php 
                                for ($j=0; $j < count($param['TOTAL_EXITOSO']) ; $j++) 
                                { 
                                    echo $param['TOTAL_EXITOSO'][$j].','; 
                                }
                            ?>
                        ],
                        color: '#006400',
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        stack: 0
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'NO EXITOSO',
                        data: 
                        [
                            <?php 
                                for ($l=0; $l < count($param['TOTAL_NOEXITOSO']) ; $l++) 
                                { 
                                    echo $param['TOTAL_NOEXITOSO'][$l].','; 
                                }
                            ?>
                        ],
                        color: '#B22222',
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        stack: 0
                    }
                ]
```

Aqui la API de referencia:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.stack

Luego, como bien te dijo Gerardo, deberas indicar si queres apilar por valor o por porcentaje. En tu caso quedaría algo asi:

```
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    },
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.1,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                },
```

Te dejo también la API de referencia:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.stacking

Aquí un ejemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZottoSL/0banf6sw/

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo solo te falta agregar lo siguiente

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: serías tan amable de indicar por que esto es lo que falta?

Comment: La opción de stacking, permite apilar las barras y al indicar el valor 'normal' te permitirá apilar por valor, tambien puedes usar el valor 'percent', espero esta explicación te sirva, saludos

Comment: @GerardoPerezThompson ¿no consideras que la explicación deba estar adjunta a tu respuesta?

Comment: Si, una disculpa, recién es mi segundo día utilizando la plataforma aun no estoy muy familiarizado a la forma de responder, sin duda lo tomare en cuenta a partir de ahora, que tengan buen día.